# Output of PHP-CLI script in Bash are not colorized

Tags: php, bash, colors

I have a following code in script.php:

```
<?php
echo "\e[0;36m Be happy ;)\e[0m";
?>
```

It is run like this:

```
~$ php script.php
```

On my linux mint desktop the output is colorized but on the remote server machine
it is not, but when I use bash there:

```
~$ echo -e "\e[0;36m Be happy ;)\e[0m";
```

I have colorized output... I have no idea what could be wrong.

Please help.

Comment: I need `echo "\033[0;36m Be happy ;)\033[0m";` here, for some reason `\e` will not work, unless I pipe it trough `echo -e`. I'm sure it's a configuration somewhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha, [found it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double):

> \e    escape (ESC or 0x1B (27) in ASCII) (since PHP 5.4.0)

< php 5.4.0. use `"\033"` instead of `"\e"`